# Powershell ForEach loop with Filename as Variable

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, openssl, foreach-object

I'm working on a script that will take .key files in a folder and convert them to .der format through OpenSSL. I'm trying to keep the current file names as a variable so the converted certificate will keep the same name, just the extension will change. Below is the code what I have tried so far:

```
$env:path="C:\Source\RFK\RFK Hardening\OpenSSL v1.1.1e\x64\bin"
$env:path="C:\Source\RFK\RFK Hardening\OpenSSL v1.1.1e\x86\bin"

$Keypath = "C:\Source\RFK\RFK Hardening\2. PKI Certificates\RFK PKI Files"
$Location = "C:\Source\RFK\RFK Hardening\2. PKI Certificates\PKI Files\RFK CSR Files"
$Keyfiles = Get-ChildItem -path $Location -Recurse -Include "*local.key"




Get-ChildItem -Path $Keypath -Recurse -Include "*.key" |

ForEach-Object {
    $KeyName = Get-Content $_.fullName

$KeyName | openssl rsa -in $_.FullName.key -out $_.FullName.der -outform DER

}
```

Comment: the `.FullName` prop is the entire name with the path AND THE EXTENSION. if you want to use that in your code then you likely set the `-In` to just `$_.FullName` and then do a replace on the `-Out` to replace the `.key` with `.der`.

Comment: It gives a different error when doing that, saying to use ```-help```. Before it was saying it couldn't open the ```-Out```  for reading

Comment: it looks like `Wasif Hasan` has shown how to do it. that code looks quite good. i would only change the regex used since it uses `.Ext` and my pref would be `\.Ext` - the escaped period is likely unneeded, tho. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_.FullName` expands to the full path of the file, also with the extension. Also completely overwriting the PATH is malpractice and paths must be separated by semicolons. Also getting content via $KeyName is not needed. $_ takes value from pipelines, so putting $KeyName will expand full path of the content, which is invalid.

```
$env:path +=";C:\Source\RFK\RFK Hardening\OpenSSL v1.1.1e\x64\bin;"
$env:path +="C:\Source\RFK\RFK Hardening\OpenSSL v1.1.1e\x86\bin;"
$Keypath = "C:\Source\RFK\RFK Hardening\2. PKI Certificates\RFK PKI Files"
$Location = "C:\Source\RFK\RFK Hardening\2. PKI Certificates\PKI Files\RFK CSR Files"
$Keyfiles = Get-ChildItem -path $Location -Recurse -Include "*local.key"
Get-ChildItem $Keypath -Recurse -Include "*.key" | ForEach {
    $OutFile = $_.Fullname.ToString().Replace(".key", ".dar") 
    # Note you can use Regex operator with Regex '\.key$', '\.dar$'
    openssl rsa -in $_.FullName -out $Outfile -outform DER
}
```

Comment: Gave this a try and it spits out an error ```openssl : unable to load Private Key```

Comment: Well, actually I think this may work! I regenerated the ```.key``` files and this time it seems to actually produce a ```.der``` version. I'll have to wait till I have a signed cert back to ensure they still link properly!

Comment: `-replace` uses regex, so you need to escape the dot. Also anchor it to the end of the string using `'\.key$'`

Comment: Theo changed Regex operator into method that does not use Regex.

Comment: Much better, although it can still replace more than just the extension. I'd prefer `[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension()` to do that securely. P.S. The second parameter for -replace is just a string taken literally. You should not escape that part and also there should be no dollar sign at the end.